# How to select result in select statement as subquery with case from int to string

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, case

In my dataset in column result I have 1 or 0. And when I select data, I would like to have string result from case: success or noresult , like in my attempt here. But nothing...
Could you help me?

```
SELECT cn.country_name, prr.revolution_campaign_reason, 
SELECT (CASE WHEN prc.success = 1 THEN "success", ELSE "noresult"),
pin.electoral_process_and_pluralism,
pin.functioning_of_government, pin.political_participation, pin.political_culture, 
pin.civil_liberties, pin.political_rights, pin.index_of_press_freedom
FROM political_revolution_campaigns prc
JOIN country_names cn ON prc.country_id = cn.id
JOIN political_indicators pin ON pin.country_id = prc.country_id
JOIN political_revolutions_reasons prr ON prc.reason_id = prr.id
ORDER BY cn.country_name;
```

Comment: Syntax: `CASE WHEN prc.success = 1 THEN 'success' ELSE 'noresult' END`

Comment: no, this is not the decision.

Comment: Remove the second SELECT. Maybe give the expression a name, `CASE WHEN prc.success = 1 THEN 'success' ELSE 'noresult' END as result`.

Comment: thank Y very much!! it was decision!